# Set breakpoint in malloc_error_break

Tags: segmentation-fault, malloc, breakpoints

I'm running a piece of code that unfortunately keeps on crashing because of a segmentation fault. The console output advises me to `set breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`.
I've been looking online for the past couple of hours, and there's a few points that are completely unclear:

1) What is malloc_error_break ? A header file ? A function ?

2) By definition, a breakpoint is a point where the function aborts if it reaches it. In this context, I'm guessing that this definition still holds, but I'm not really sure what "reaching `malloc_error_break`" means.

3) Is it possible to do this without using Xcode ? I'm only writing a relatively small script and every time I've tried using Xcode I've been completely overwhelmed by all the extra frills. I try to stick to Emacs and compiling on the Terminal.

4) How do I set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` ?

Feel free to answer only some parts of this question. Parts 1, 2, and 3 are attempts to address my woeful ignorance, part 4 is a direct solution to my problem.

Thanks !

Comment: You can use a debugger like gdb (it's a command line tool) and set a breakpoint through this. I am not aware of this error. But you ll get more info for the seg fault through gdb for sure. Compile your source with the -g flag and pass the executable to gdb

Comment: Thanks ! This worked beautifully, I was able to use gdb to resolve the issue !